# Search for records in child table based on Date and time from master table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to compare between 2 tables ( table –A and table-B) using a DateTime field and get the matching record from  Table-B. 
Table A is master table to Table B

[image]

Based on the above example, I need retrieve record matching Master-ID=1 based on Date ( as the time is different) where as for Master-ID=2 , there are multiple records with same date but with time only one matching record.

How do I get the highlighted rows from Table-B.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What problems are you running into when you try to get the desired results?

Comment: I tried using  CONVERT(date, DateTimeField) to compare between 2 tables, this is comparing only dates and get more than one record for ID=2 . I used  DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, DateTimeField), this will not return any record for ID=1.  How do I search for records based on dates and if more than one record found , search based on time.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from tableA a
inner join tableA b on  convert(date,a.dateA)=convert(date,b.DateB)
```